# Question Folder but no Startup Options

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I came home to my Mac Book Pro (late 2009) showing me the blinking question mark folder.

I followed all the instructions available online (Reset NVRAM, SMC) but neither boot screen (pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> during/before start-up) nor Internet recovery (<kbd>Command</kbd>+ <kbd>r</kbd> during/before start-up) shows me anything. They just lead to an empty grey startup screen.

I attached an external hard drive with bootable macOS that I have used on this computer before, but it changes nothing - boot screen doesn't show.

EDIT: I solved the Problem by exchanging the IDE Cable. I do not know how this has effected the start-up process, but now i was able to boot from the external drive and from my drive as well.

Comment: I have experienced similar problem with my MacBook Pro recently. I have tried similar steps (apart from connecting an external bootable drive) with no success. I was able to come to a conclusion that the connector to the internal boot media was loose. What worked for me was a rather non-conventional approach. After shutting down the MacBook completely by long pressing the power button, simply lift it, hold it firmly and shake it horizontally. I was able to "fix" the loose connection of the drive this way and computer was able to detect the startup disk and booted fine.

Comment: Failing that sounds like it is time to take it to an Apple store or other Apple repair location.

Comment: @steve-chambers They stopped supporting that model since there are no replacement parts left to order.

Comment: Independent repair shops often use non-Apple sources for parts. Like used computers. A good independant repair tech *might* be able to fix it, just sayin'